# ONNX not using GPU

Tags: python, onnx

The code utilizes the WD14 model to caption images

```
import glob

from imgutils.tagging import get_wd14_tags

for image in glob.glob('/picture_store/*.JPG'):
    rating, features, chars = get_wd14_tags(image)

    print(image, rating, features, chars)
```

It gives the correct result but runs only on the CPU. Any other KI application e.g. pytorch, stable_diffusion runs smooth on the GPU of this system.

I tracked this down to

```
 /home/volker/workspace/venvs/img-caption-DfsJQ_L--py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py  [line 465]

 providers ->
 ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']

 sess.initialize_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
```

Since the code vanishes into C++, I cannot debug further and can only blame Microsoft.

Even some hacks like

```
self._providers = ['CUDAExecutionProvider']
```

do not help. ONNX is installed as 1.16.2 of

```
 onnx-runtime-gpu
```

`ONNX` claims that `CUDAExecutionProvider` is available.

```
 ort.get_all_providers()
    ['TensorrtExecutionProvider', 'CUDAExecutionProvider', 'MIGraphXExecutionProvider', 
 'ROCMExecutionProvider', 'OpenVINOExecutionProvider', 'DnnlExecutionProvider', 
 'TvmExecutionProvider', 'VitisAIExecutionProvider', 'QNNExecutionProvider', 
 'NnapiExecutionProvider', 'JsExecutionProvider', 'CoreMLExecutionProvider', 
 'ArmNNExecutionProvider', 'ACLExecutionProvider', 'DmlExecutionProvider', 
 'RknpuExecutionProvider', 'WebNNExecutionProvider', 'XnnpackExecutionProvider', 
 'CANNExecutionProvider', 'AzureExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']
```

My Installation:

```
Debian Bookworm
Driver Version: 545.23.06    CUDA Version: 12.3
```

Any help appreciated

Cheers
Volker

Comment: Are you using Raspberry p?

Comment: No. Normal Intel I5 server hardware

Comment: Could you show the code which constructs the `InferenceSession` object (incl. `sess_options` and `provider_options`). What model are trying to run? Does the CPU execution produce correct results?

Comment: Changed initial post

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

the environment variable ONNX_MODE controls if the CPU or the GPU is used.
Setting ONNX_MODE=cuda forced the code to use Cuda. This gaves finally an error message:

```
E:onnxruntime:Default, provider_bridge_ort.cc:1480 TryGetProviderInfo_CUDA] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/provider_bridge_ort.cc:1193 onnxruntime::Provider& onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get() [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director
```

Which shows that there is a library version conflict. From here one can start to fix things.

But I decided to use [onnx2pytorch](https://github.com/Talmaj/onnx2pytorch) to convert the ONNX to pytorch and use the pytorch ecosystem.